# Unity: How to keep animation keyframe position in the transform

Tags: unity, animation

I want to make a paired animation- 
I have 2 characters. One is doing a Grabbing-Move on a character who is grabbed.

But for that its necessary to animate all those animations on a character on a certain pose.

And for now I can only do the "grabber" animations on a T-Pose (first character has T-Pose always when I try to animate the second).

But I dont want to do animations on a "T-Pose"
I want to animate the Second Character(Grabber-) on a "Grabbed" - Pose.

I already have a "Grabbed-" Animation.
Now I want the "Grabbed-"Animation to stay.

For that I need to "safe" the current keyframe position of the first character - while animating the second character

How is that possible?

Comment: can you put some reference image? it's little confusing